# How to merge strings of same index, in multiple lists, into one?

Tags: python

I need to merge 2 strings of the same index from different lists into one. For example:

```
a=["Hello", "Hi"]
b=["World", "friends"]
```

I want to obtain a new list which would be:

```
["HelloWorld", "Hifriends"]
```

I've tried multiple ways of doing this, but none seem to work.

Comment: What ways? Give a [mre].

Comment: I will not give you the exact anwer because this seems some homwork but you can iterate over 2 lists using `zip`: `for el1,el2 in zip(a,b)`  is the equivalent to work with `el1= a[0]` , `el2=b[0]` in first step, `el1= a[1]` , `el2=b[1]` in second step, and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate both the lists in parallel using `zip`, then concatenate the items, you can use List-comprehension:

```py
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
['HelloWorld', 'Hifriends']
```

Comment: `["".join(p) for p in zip(a,b)]` could be an option if delimiter between strings needed.

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same length

```py
def merge_lists(lst1, lst2):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(lst1)):
        result.append(lst1[i] + lst2[i])
    return result
```

Modify it to your liking.

Or like so:

```py
[a[x] + b[x] for x in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a universal solution:

```py
def join_by_index(*lists, delimiter=""):
    return [delimiter.join(items) for items in zip(*lists)]
```

Usage:

```py
a = ["Hello", "Hi"]
b = ["Python", "my"]
c = ["World", "friends"]

print(join_by_index(a, c))
print(join_by_index(a, b, c))
print(join_by_index(a, b, c, delimiter=" "))
```

Output:

```py
['HelloWorld', 'Hifriends']
['HelloPythonWorld', 'Himyfriends']
['Hello Python World', 'Hi my friends']
```